# How do I hook into Capture form onPost event?

Tags: plugin-development, events, hook

I am writing a new plugin to hook into a POST event from a bespoke form plugin called "Capture". The Capture plugin fires two different events; the code taken from `/craft/plugins/capture/services/Capture_SubmissionsService.php`

```
public function onBeforePost(Event $event) {
    $this->raiseEvent('onBeforePost', $event);
}

public function onPost(Event $event) {
    $this->raiseEvent('onPost', $event);
}
```

I called die(); inside each one so I know they are being called.

My new plugin is very simple. I would like to be able to hook into the onPost event and receive the form data. My plugin is very simple for now as I am just concerned with hooking into the event. The below example has getName, getDeveloper, getDescription, getVersion etc removed for ease of reading. This is the only file in my plugin: `/craft/plugins/myplugin/MyPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin extends BasePlugin {

   public function init() {
      craft()->on('capture.onPost', function(Event $event){
         die('onPost <pre>'.print_r($event,true).'</pre>');
      });
   }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be get called. I am assuming that I need something other than `capture.onPost`.

I have used the following docs, but would appreciate any help.

https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events

https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference

Comment: Might sound like a silly question, but is MyPlugin installed and enabled in the Craft control panel?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I have found my problem now and will post as an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a bit of a clumsy way, but the capture plugin has two services, `capture_forms` and `capture_submissions`. The first deals with saving the forms within the CraftCMS admin, the latter is for dealing with the form submissions.

I had to simply change my listener to `craft()->on('capture_submissions.onPost', function(Event $event){...});` and I can see the event data.